# Possible to share SQLite DB between PhoneGap and Native code?

Tags: iphone, android, sqlite, cordova, analytics

I am writing a native iPhone and Android app using Sencha Touch inside Phonegap and my client is very keen for me to include Analytics.

The application needs to function happily offline so I need an analytics solution that can remember activity occurring while offline and updating the server once online again.

My thoughts are to store events from within the JS to a store that can be checked at a regular interval on the device and posted to the server.

My question is whether a SQLite DB could be used for this using the Phonegap API and whether this DB could then be accessed from the native code?

I suspect not and that the best option would be to write to a text file.

Any thoughts or suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this seems to be to write a Phonegap Plugin that lets you call a method from inside Phonegap to a method in your native application.